# assigning Rvalue reference to Lvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
int&& rv = 10;
int& lv = rv; //no error
```

How is this possible?

Is this related to "reference collapsing rule"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 int&& rv = 10; 
 int& lv = rv; //no error
```

First of all, a *named* object is *never* an rvalue. Second, since `rv` is *named* object, it is not a rvalue, even though it binds to rvalue. Since `rv` is lvalue, it can bind to lvalue without any problem.

Note that rvalue-ness is a property of an *expression*, not a *variable*. In the above example, an rvalue is created out of `10` and binds to `rv`, which as I said, is lvalue.

Comment: What happens if `lv = 20;`? Does `rv` hold unnamed variable assigned `10`? (if not we assign on constant;)

Comment: @ikh, if you mean `int & lv = rv;` then `lv = 20`. That is perfectly fine. However, if you meant `int & lv = 20;` then that is invalid.  You can think of `&&` as magician which makes an lvalue to bind to *rvalue expression*. Since you can write `&&` only in a declaration of the variable, you can write `int && x = 20;` even though `x` is a lvalue. There is another magician known as `const` which makes an lvalue to bind to `rvalue` as in : `int const & lv = 20;`, which is valid.

Comment: This answer is inaccurate. There are contexts such as the implicit-move in a `return` statement where rvalue references are considered to be xvalues, not lvalues.