# Can rvalue references be passed on as const references?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

Consider the following example `struct`:

```
struct A {
    int i;

    void init(const A &a)
    {
        this->i = a.i;
    }

    A(int i)
    {
        this->i = i;
    }

    A(const A &a) = delete;
    A &operator=(const A &a) = delete;

    A(A &&a)
    {
        init(a); // Is this allowed?
    }

    A &operator=(A &&a)
    {
        init(a); // Is this allowed?
        return *this;
    }
};
```

The rvalue reference `A &&a` is passed on to a function accepting a `const A &a`, i.e. a constant lvalue reference. Is this allowed and resulting in well defined behaviour in C++?

Comment: The name of a variable whose type is "rvalue reference" is an lvalue, and can be used like every other lvalue.

Comment: @cpplearner So that would imply that this is valid? I saw an comment here a second ago that said "no".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [assigning Rvalue reference to Lvalue reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37894068/assigning-rvalue-reference-to-lvalue-reference)

Comment: alternative duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369511/why-can-you-indirectly-bind-an-rvalue-to-an-lvalue-reference-but-not-directly

Comment: @uneven_mark While the questions are similar, the answers don't give a definite "yes or no" on whether this is intended to work the way that it does.

Comment: @HerpDerpington I am not sure what you mean with "*is intended to work the way it does*". As explained in the duplicates your code is syntactically correct and semantically I assumed it was clear that the bound reference behaves the same way as all other references from the fact that the duplicates' answers didn't mention anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is allowed.

Note, that value category of the expression `a` is lvalue, even though `a`'s declared type is rvalue reference.

Furthermore, if you create an rvalue from `a` with `std::move`, your code is still well-formed, as an rvalue can be bound to a const lvalue reference:

```
init(std::move(a)); // std::move(a) is an rvalue (to be precise, xvalue), but still OK
```

Comment: Which `a` exactly? :D Do you mean the parameter of `A(A &&a)` and `A &operator=(A &&a)`?

Comment: @HerpDerpington: yes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast `a` to an rvalue in your example to get the intended effect, because variable names themselves are lvalues (this is a tricky detail of lvalues and rvalues in C++).  So as written, it's correct C++ but not doing what you think it's doing.

If you cast it, using [`std::move(a)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) instead of just `a`, the code now does what you want and is still correct.  This is because of a special rule in C++ that temporaries can be bound to **const lvalues**, a more detailed discussion of which can be found [here](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/).  This features comes as a great convenience when you have code like:

```
void ProcessData(const std::vector<int>& input_vector);
```

and then you want to test it with the following:

```
ProcessData(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
```

This saves you from having to explicitly create the object before passing it on as a **const** lvalue reference.  Note the const here is critical, without it the code is incorrect.  There is a more detailed discussion of this rationale for this choice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object?rq=1).

Comment: What does using `std::move(a)` instead of `a` change here? Both will still call `init(const A &a)`, since there is no overload `init(A &&a)`.

Comment: What I want is simply that `i` gets assigned the same value as it has in the instance passed as rvalue to the move constructor/operator.

Comment: @HerpDerpington Yes it does (assuming of course the object bound to the initial reference is in its lifetime, but that requirement applies always anyway).

Comment: Good question @uneven_mark, I glazed over that a little.  Using `std::move` here causes you to actually pass an rvalue to the function `init`, without `std::move` you are passing an lvalue.  So the important point is that without it, the code is not doing what the OP is asking about, i.e. is passing an rvalue into a parameter that's expected to be a const lvalue reference.  At the same time, in both cases the code will work and do the same thing, in fact I wouldn't be surprised if some compilers produce the same code for both (unless I've missed a tricky subtlety).

Comment: @Apollys By "passing an rvalue" i actually meant passing `A &&a` as in the move constructors parameter list.

Comment: *"but not doing what you think it's doing"* makes it sound as if the resulting programs behavior would be different. To consider the expression put as argument being a lvalue rather than rvalue as *"not doing what you think it's doing"* sounds a bit far-fetched to me (the potential overloading issue which doesn't apply here aside). And in fact I don't see OP claiming anywhere that they are passing a rvalue, only that they are passing a rvalue reference, which is correct.

Comment: @HerpDerpington In the line `init(a)` that you have, `a` is an lvalue.  So if your question is, does your code work exactly as written, then yes (almost trivially so once you're given the previous statement), because you're passing an lvalue to a function that takes an lvalue reference.

Comment: @Apollys But then my question is why is it an lvalue if the variable was declared as `A &&a`? Or rather I can see that it is. Nevertheless, using it as an lvalue seems counterintuitive and the question would be whether this is allowed.

Comment: Well that's one of those tricky details (as I mentioned in my answer).  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620750/why-are-rvalues-references-variables-not-rvalue) is a good discussion of it.

Comment: @Apollys From the top answer of that post: "`T&&` is the type rvalue reference. An rvalue reference can only bind to an rvalue (without a `static_cast` being involved), but it is otherwise an lvalue of type rvalue reference." If the type is "rvalue reference" why does it cast/is it being casted to a "regular" lvalue reference?

Comment: Try the second answer, I found it explains some elements more clearly.  The distinction between lvalues and rvalues is quite complicated and I don't think I can do it justice in a comment.